# Passing children in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first time to develop a react application.

I wanted to display 5 buttons in a table. The first approach I did is to hardcode it in Table.js

```
Table.js

        <Button hidden={controlButton} onClick={() => reprocessConfirmation()}>
          Reprocess
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button hidden={controlButton} onClick={() => reprocessConfirmation()}>
          View Details
        </Button>
        <Button hidden={!controlButton} onClick={() => updateConfirmation()}>
          Update
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button hidden={!controlButton} onClick={() => deleteConfirmation()}>
          Delete
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button hidden={!controlButton} onClick={() => resequenceConfirmation()}>
          Resequence
        </Button>
```

But Table.js is designed to be reusable, so I was tasked to move these to index.js. I tried it by creating a var that has the function containing the buttons and return it to Table.js and display it using children props using this line {this.children}

```
index.js

const testButton = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button>Test1</button>
        <button>Test2</button>
        <button>Test3</button>
        <button>Test4</button>
        <button>Test5</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MyTable
        {...{
          testButton
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

In Table.js I added

```
table.js


export default function MyTable({
  testButton,
  ...props
}) {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table {...getTableProps()}>
        *****{props.children}
      </Table>
    </React.Fragment>
```

It seems that when I use 
this.children= it is undefined
props.children= does not display anything

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could try passing the buttons as a children of the component and then showing it by calling {props.children}

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't clear. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Also include a clear, specific statement of what isn't working, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: you are not passing `pageOptions`, see the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I changed the context of the question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't pass `pageOptions` prop to MyTable component as you render children based on it's length.